# Div height differs to what is declared on the property in IE11 only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to create a webpage with a vertically and horizontally centred div, with defined height and width, split down the middle. Almost like an open book.

I have no problems with achieving this in Chrome/Firefox/Safari but cannot get this to reflect in IE11 as half of the 'book' has a greater height than the other half, which leads me to believe the 'height: 863px' property in .loginContainer is causing the issue as it looks marginally better once I move this.

Not totally sure but I think I need to specify an explicit height for the container to stop the content inside becoming squashed - simply removing this property allows the container to be too small so content looks cramped once I put text in there.

I have tried to remove the property and use padding on the content inside to create a bit of space but I don't feel this is the right approach and makes it appear totally different to the mock ups I'm following.

I have created a JSFiddle found here;

https://jsfiddle.net/e02cqdr6/2/

and think the issue lies at;

```
.loginContainer {
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 1;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1338px;
height: 863px;
border-radius: 15px;}
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: rgb(27, 27, 27);
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  /* for firefox */
}

.pageContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.loginContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1338px;
  height: 863px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.leftContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  width: 621px;
  border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;
}

.rightContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  align-items: center;
  width: 717px;
  border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
}

.titleContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border: 1px solid rgb(243, 241, 241);
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(243, 241, 241);
  color: grey;
}

a {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  color: orange;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nextBtn {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(134, 200, 223);
  color: #ffffff;
}

.assetContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.descContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.descHeading {
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.productDesc {
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  width: 440px;
}

.assetLogoBlack {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.logoContainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.servicesLogo {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageContainer">
  <div class="loginContainer">
    <div class="leftContainer">
      <div class="assetContainer">
        <div class="logoContainer">
          <img src="/assets/ilogo.svg" class="servicesLogo">
          <img src="/assets/cslogo.svg" class="servicesLogo">
        </div>
        <div class="descContainer">
          <p class="descHeading">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          <p class="productDesc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi volutpat sodales arcu id tincidunt. Ut a laoreet risus. Suspendisse potenti. Curabitur in ultricies risus. Vivamus convallis non libero commodo malesuada. Cras eu neque vulputate
            lectus sagittis ullamcorper sit amet vitae ante. Integer pellentesque neque eget molestie vehicula. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rightContainer">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I expect it to look like this: https://ibb.co/T2Cc59V
but instead it looks like this:  https://ibb.co/M8zZ9rs

To reiterate, the problem only exists in IE11.

Nothing stands out as obvious and I have no errors thrown so am totally stumped as to how to resolve this.

Comment: Why do you need `margin: 0 auto;` for the loginContainer? You already aligned it vertically with the page container. What happens if you remove it?

Comment: It works fine for me , either the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e02cqdr6/2/embedded/result,css,html,js  or the snippet . What sort of IE11 do you use for test ? is it from a folder or on a web host ? I run a genuine IE11 , so i have no doubts it works, unless your fiddle or snippet misses part of your code.

Comment: I try to test your sample code with IE 11 browser and looks like your code is working fine with IE browser. Here is the testing result. Ref: https://i.postimg.cc/cHrgdkCS/253.png I suggest you to again try to test the issue with your above posted code to see the results. It can be possible that some other code in your original CSS causing this issue. So you can also try to check for that to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the input, I have ended up stripping this back to bare bones to see what is causing the issue as it does work fine on the jsfiddle. It turns out it is the white space around the asset I need to use for the background makes it appear as though it doesn't fill the parent div.